# How do you get the new quartenion if you rotate a vector around itself , meaning , the position of the vector won't change

Tags: math, quaternions

[Vector rotates around itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avocP.png)
, In blender for example , a quartenion ,

```
Quaternion (w=0.8536, x=0.3536, y=0.3536, z=-0.1464) ,
```

when rotated 45 degrees results to ,

```
Quaternion (w=0.6533, x=0.3827, y=0.6533, z=-0.0000) ,
```

What's the formula to get the new quaternion?

Comment: You should know the formula by yourself to get the final answer, or you can try to use Matlab?

Comment: If the vector didn't change from the rotation, then *you can't retrieve information about the rotation*.

Comment: Is it true that your question is how to recover the rotation axis given a vector, the image of this vector after the rotation, and the rotation angle?

Answer (score 0):

A (unit) quaternion represents more than just a 3D vector. It represents a rotation. And you could also interpret it as a representation of a coordinate system (defined by the coordinate system that results from the global coordinate system by the specified rotation). And if you transform a coordinate system represented by a quaternion `q1` with a transform represented by another quaternion `r`, you get the transformed quaternion `q2` by

```
q2 = r * q1
```